# Plot using a log scale in R

Tags: r, plot

I've started using R recently and I have this issue, so when I want to plot glm regression output using a log scale for my variable y, it doesn't work, even my X abscisse do not change from numbers (which are the age values) to age (the name of the values), to explain more, this is what I've done :

```
reg=glm(visites~age, data=database, family=poisson)

y = predict(reg, type="response",newdata=data.frame(age=66:96))
par(mfrow=c(1,2))

plot(66:96,y,type="l")

plot(66:96,y,type="l", log = "y")
```

[image]

Comment: By "abscisse" do you mean "axis"?

Comment: Does `plot(66:96,log(y),type="l")` achieve that?

Comment: yes axis (sorry) and log(y) is not really what i want, i need a log scale

Comment: Welcome to stack oververflow. I'm not sure I understand your question. This seams to work though `y<- 1:10; plot.default(1:10,y,log="y")`. I'm not sure I understand how the log scale parameter work but it is a scale problem. `plot.default(65:95,seq(5.8,6.4,length.out=31),log="y")`. So it seams you would need to do `plot.default(65:95,log(seq(5.8,6.4,length.out=31)),log="y")`

Comment: thank you very much and for everybody for your answers, it is really helpful for me to learn, but to be honest, my real problem is that the scale log do not appear in my plot, it's not about script or something like that, all i want is that for my plat to show log scale on the Y, and age at the axis, without like writing them to link between predict and the fact that the function is not really linear.

Answer (score 0):

You aren't going to see much curvature (induced by `log="y"`) when the range and location of the axis is this small. If we "shift" (bring closer to 0) and "scale" (expand), we see dramatically different curves with the same basic relationship between the `x` and `y` data.

```r
x <- 66:96
# an approximation of your data
y <- 6.5 - 0.8 * (seq_along(x) - 1) / length(x)

par(mfrow = c(2, 3))
plot(x, y, type = "l", log = "y", main = "Original")
y1 <- y - min(y) + 1
plot(x, y1, type = "l", log = "y", main = "Shifted")
y2 <- y - min(y) + 0.1
plot(x, y2, type = "l", log = "y", main = "Shifted More")
y3 <- 1000 * y
plot(x, y3, type = "l", log = "y", main = "Scaled")
y4 <- 1000 * (y - min(y)) + 1
plot(x, y4, type = "l", log = "y", main = "Shifted, Scaled")
y4 <- 1000 * (y - min(y)) + 0.1
plot(x, y4, type = "l", log = "y", main = "Shifted More, Scaled")
```

[image: 6-pack of plots]

Comment: well received, :) please may i ask you about log="y", normally if you put log = "y", log scale will appear on the plot, but it is not the case for me, what should i do ?

Comment: Not sure what you mean. All plots above used it, and while it isn't always obvious, the bottom-middle is the clearest. The bottom-right is obscured a little due to scientific notation, something that can be remedied without too much difficulty. Consider using `plot(..., yaxt="n")` then follow-up with `axis(...)` to manually control the positions and labels you want ticks and labels.